# Backbone - parsing JSON ID

Tags: json, parsing, backbone.js

I'm trying to parse JSON data using Backbone from a remote API. Here's what I've got so far:

```
  // --------------------------------------------------
// MODELS
// --------------------------------------------------

var VideoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: '_id',
    parse: function(){
        this.id = response._id;
    }
});
var videoModel = new VideoModel({ parse:true });

// --------------------------------------------------
// COLLECTIONS
// --------------------------------------------------

var VideosCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: VideoModel,
    url: 'redacted',
    parse: function(response){
        this.videos = response.data;
        this.cid    = response.cid;
        return response.data;
    },
    render: function(){
        this.collection.forEach(this.addone, this);
    }
});

var videosCollection = new VideosCollection();

videosCollection.fetch({
    success: function(videos){
        console.log('success!');
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('failed.');
    }
});

// --------------------------------------------------
// VIEWS
// --------------------------------------------------

var VideoView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<%= videoModel.id %>'),
    render: function(){
        this$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    }
});

var videoView = new VideoView({});


var VideosCollectionView = Backbone.View.extend({});

var videosCollectionView = new VideosCollectionView({ 
    collection: videosCollection,
    render: function(){
        this.collection.forEach(this.addOne, this);
    },
    addOne: function(videoModel){
        this.$el.append(videoView.el);
    }
});
```

What I'm having trouble with is that console.log(videoModel.id) is still `undefined`.

The data is a playlist of videos, which is valid JSON:

```
 {
   "total":24,
   "per_page":24,
   "current_page":1,
   "last_page":1,
   "from":1,
   "to":24,
   "data":[
      {
         "_id":"55d1bb50140ba04c1d8b4583",
```

Be glad for some prompts in the right direction - especially since I had it working this morning and then ... reverted to a previous version without saving.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From documentstion of [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) method:

> The function is passed the raw response object, and should return the
>   attributes hash to be set on the model. The default implementation is
>   a no-op, simply passing through the JSON response.

So by default it works like this:

```
parse: function(data) {
    return data;
}
```

Your code now returns nothing and model takes no data.

As I see you want to set `id` attribute but you already have setted `idAttribute` property with `_id` and there is `_id` in your data so it should work fine without parse at all. Try to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I was trying to parse via a Collection instead of a Model. So I would never have got the id I was looking for. For some reason.

I needed to move the URL into the Model and parse from there:

```
var VideoModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
   idAttribute: '_id',
   url: 'redacted',
   parse: function(response){
      var id = response._id;
      var cid = response.cid;
   return response.data;
   },
}),
```

Now when I do `videoModel.get(1)` in the console, it returns the value of the first item in my array.